# How to silence text messages for specific contacts on Android?

Tags: android, sms, contacts, silent, vibration

I have a [GroupMe](https://groupme.com/) contact on my Android phone which I get messages from all the time. It is really annoying, so I can either #mute text the GroupMe server and stop getting messages or mute my phone vibrations altogether. The problem with these solutions is that I don't want to completely mute the messages from the server altogether. I want to be able to read them when I decide to. I also don't want to mute my phone altogether because then I can't tell if someone else tried to text me.

I tried searching online for help on the topic and I came across the [Contact Vibrate](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=ac.vibration&hl=en) application. It had a bunch of features and seemed pretty messy in organization. You could set custom vibrate patterns for each of your contacts. I noticed that it had plenty of default vibrate patterns, but none that just vibrated once and none that vibrated zero times. I tried to create one that didn't vibrate, but that didn't work. I ended up deleting the app altogether.

I still haven't found a way to silence the vibrate messages for that specific contact while allowing the messages themselves to be received. Solution?

Answer (score 1):

Try [Messanger](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.messaging&hl=en) by google. tap and hold on a conversation inside messenger and you will get an option to mute.

Comment: The messenger app slows down when there is a text message history.

Comment: This is no longer true. In the current version, you need to open the conversation, click the three dots, go to Details then Notifications and turn of Show notifications. So, instead of a two step process, now you have to do five steps...

Answer (score 1):

This may be a bit old, but I had the same question and stumbled upon a simple solution.  Download a silent MP3 file onto your phone and set that as your specialized notification tone for the desired contact(s).